# How to use authorisation with user roles with my own database

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, ef-code-first, authorize-attribute

As the question states I would like to check what type of user is logged in by using data annotation

```
[Authorize(Roles="Admin")]
```

I have seen multiple questions and tutorial but none of them explain it clearly or use older mvc.

Is there a simple way to achieve that without using the stock authentication system provided with individual account authorization?

I simply do have a table for users with usernames passwords etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to deal with two things Authentication and Authorization.

**Authentication**

You can authenticate users using [Owin forms Authentication](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/07/03/understanding-owin-forms-authentication-in-mvc-5/) or the old fashioned Forms Authentication if you prefer.

**Authorization**

For authorization you can create a [custom Role Provider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fw7xh74.aspx) if you want to use Roles (as your did in your sample code) or you can use [Claims Authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/claims).

This [article](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/607392/custom-role-providers) is from 2013 but I successfully followed it to implement a custom role provider  in my MVC5 application.

Comment: Thank you, I went through all the links but I believe I will simply add a session it seems like such an overkill the application is for a coursework not for enterprise, so spending X hours to implement authentication and authorization seems like an overkill when I have a ton of functionality to apply.

The only roles I needed were customer/staff I could use I guess [Authorize] for both and for methods that staff uses I could add if[Session... to check if this is actually staff member.